# How can I directly go to the Edit view of a webpart programmatically in SharePoint 2007 and 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, share

I would like to provide a link on webpart content. On click of the link i want to switch to the **edit view** **(Where user can set properties of Webpart)**. See the image below. How can I go to the following view directly programmatically in SharePoint 2007 and 2010.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes found the answer.

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="ButtonEdit" style="padding-right:5px;" runat="server"
                  Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12px" Font-Underline="True"  
                  ForeColor="#003399">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
```

**C# Code**

```
ButtonEdit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:MSOTlPn_ShowToolPane2Wrapper('Edit', this,'" + Parent.ID + "');");
```

I took help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102980/how-to-make-a-link-to-open-to-a-toolpart-in-webpart)